# easy_install install on Windows 7 32 bit

Tags: python-3.x, easy-install

Trying to find out how to install or find easy_install on my Windows 7 32bit machine with Python 3.2.3 installed.

On a different machine with Windows 7 64 bit Python 3.2.3, easy_install was installed automatically into c:\python32\Scripts.

I found some instructions on how to install easy_install [here](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/EasyInstall#installing-easy-install), which led me to [this page](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#windows) which tells me that to install easy_install, I need to install setuptools with the provided .exe (couldn't find). Also, I'm left to wonder what setuptools has to do with easy_install?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: @nhahtdh those links appear to be for Python2.x. Needing for 3.x.

Comment: Use distribute instead: https://bitbucket.org/tarek/distribute/overview

Answer (score 5):

`easy_install` is included with distribute. The simplest way to install it on Windows is from this page:

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#distribute